# Kubernetes enforce spreading replicas out across worker nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I have an on-prem Kubernetes cluster and recently it required a physical restart of all the worker nodes (run three worker nodes). When the pods came back up, I noticed all the pods scheduled on a single physical worker node instead of being spread out evenly across the three worker nodes. I am assuming the other two worker nodes took longer to come back online from the restart and Kubernetes just scheduled all our applications on the only worker node up.

Is there a way in the deployment yaml to specify that all deployment replicas should be spread out eventually across all worker nodes? I.E. prevent Kubernetes from starting all pods on a single worker node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this thing called [inter pod anti affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity) that does exactly this.

From k8s docs:

> Inter-pod affinity and anti-affinity allow you to constrain which
> nodes your pod is eligible to be scheduled based on labels on pods
> that are already running on the node rather than based on labels on
> nodes. The rules are of the form "this pod should (or, in the case of
> anti-affinity, should not) run in an X if that X is already running
> one or more pods that meet rule Y".

Example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-server
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web-store
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web-store
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - web-store
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
      - name: web-app
        image: nginx:1.16-alpine
```

It will make sure that no two pods of the same deployment are schedules on the same node. If there are no more nodes available to schedule a pod, pods will stay in ***pending*** state (won't get schduled).

Comment: I tried this, and getting the following error when redeploying the deployment: ` Warning  FailedScheduling  29s   default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 3 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/anti-affinity, 3 node(s) didn't match pod anti-affinity rules.`

Comment: Is this because I have 3 worker nodes and the deployment has replicas `3` so trying to do the `kubectl apply` can't find another worker node?